# Apache Server Path Location in Debian

Tags: server, virtualbox, apache2, debian

I'd installed KOHA Integrated Library System using pre-made image through a Virtual Box. I want to find the path location of my Apache Server so that I can manipulate/modify the files for my customization.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

I tried to run the following code:

```
grep DocumentRoot /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ -R
```

but an output shows :

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default: DocumentRoot /var/www 
grep: etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mathlibrary: Permission denied
```

Am I doing the right thing?

Comment: Are you talking of the IP of localhost?

Comment: @muru --> No, I want to know the path location of my localhost :)

Comment: Are you trying to access the guest (VM) from the host (real machine)? Or the host from the guest? Or something else? Note that "localhost" is a technical term that refers to a machine [as accessed from itself via its loopback interface](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247625/what-is-the-loopback-device-and-how-do-i-use-it).

Comment: Also, how does this relate to Ubuntu? Is one of the machines an Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be in any number of places. If KOHA uses Apache, try this:

```
grep DocumentRoot /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ -R
```

Replace `apache2` with `nginx` if KOHA uses nginx.

Comment: KOHA uses apache. I tried what you've said but it only shows     </etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default: DocumentRoot /var/www >   grep: etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mathlibrary: Permission denied  >                           I am doing the right thing?

Comment: @AlyssaGono whatever it shows, please edit the question to post the output. It's hard to read output in comments.

Comment: @AlyssaGono, it looks like `/var/www` is the DocumentRoot which AFAIK is the default for Apache anyway.

Comment: @Trengot depends on the version. On 14.04, the default is `/var/www/html`. It could be something custom for KOHA.

Comment: @AlyssaGono run the command with `sudo`. You need the `DocumentRoot` for `mathlibrary`, not the default site.