# Three networking devices?

Tags: networking

When i use the command `ip a` I see three wireless adapters or devices

[image: this is a screen shot of what the case looks like]

My router's wireless DHCP clients i see two mac adresses like this:

[image: screen shot from the modem config]

-what do you think guys , is it like some software trying to fake an adapter identity or what??

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy-paste the text, and use the formatting tools to make it look nice. (For details, see [the formatting guide](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) and [Why do people post screenshots of their terminals?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/301745))

Comment: Related: [What is the loopback device and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247625/what-is-the-loopback-device-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: FWIW, 98:0c:a5 is a Motorola MAC address. [Source](https://macvendors.com)

Comment: hhh yeah am aware of that but am in a bit of hurry ; this is why it's messed up a bit "in fact a lot" sorry again ; the main question now is why there is two devices connected to my router at the moment?
much appreciated ;)

Comment: @Gamer_One I would guess you have a Motorola Android phone.

Comment: i'v checked every device i own non of it is actually connected nor any other device in my house ; and i don't think that the router is  hacked ;'weird' huh??

Comment: i think it has to do with "macchanger" cause i use it a lot !

Comment: Thanks a lot @wjandrea for help ; however i haven't figured out what the motorola device was, anyways ; by reseting my routers SSID and PASSWORD i were able to solve the issue.