# iptables prevents me from connecting

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and my current iptables rules are from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/what-is-a-solid-iptables-configuration-for-my-desktop); `iptables -L` gives:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

and with these I can't connect anywhere. I have to flush the list and accept again (from scratch) to restore connectivity. Why are these not working?

Comment: You mean that you can't access Internet with these rules or your instance is not accessible from outside? Please post also the output of `sudo iptables -S`.

Comment: You need to allow the local interface: `sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`

Comment: @DougSmythies please make it an answer :) also please explain why that is necessary if possible. Thanks for fixing it!

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81107/why-must-loopback-traffic-be-authorized-using-iptables-to-get-web-access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow the local loopback interface:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Sometimes inter-process communications takes place over the loopback interface. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247625/what-is-the-loopback-device-and-how-do-i-use-it) for more information about the loopback interface.

EDIT: So I have exactly this on one of my test computers:

```
doug@s17:~$ sudo iptables -v -x -n -L

Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      94     9843 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    5093  6056565 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       8      613 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3904 packets, 321224 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Now, if I wanted to gain further insight into the rejected packets, I could also log them:

```
sudo iptables --insert INPUT 3 --jump LOG --log-prefix "INPUT-REJECT:" --log-level info
```

And then (after some more rejects) look at /var/log/syslog:

```
Dec 12 14:18:42 s17 kernel: [2007598.577383] INPUT-REJECT:IN=ens5 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:21:9b:f9:21:26:08:00 SRC=192.168.111.101 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=42 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=4970 PROTO=UDP SPT=55705 DPT=3289 LEN=22
Dec 12 14:18:42 s17 kernel: [2007598.695347] INPUT-REJECT:IN=ens5 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:21:9b:f9:21:26:08:00 SRC=192.168.111.101 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=42 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=4971 PROTO=UDP SPT=55708 DPT=3289 LEN=22
Dec 12 14:18:43 s17 kernel: [2007599.014201] INPUT-REJECT:IN=ens5 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:21:9b:f9:21:26:08:00 SRC=192.168.111.101 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=42 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=4972 PROTO=UDP SPT=55712 DPT=3289 LEN=22
```

And I observe that they are just broadcast packets from this computer that I am typing on now.

Comment: Although it's a bit weird, I can browse websites such as this one, but not google.com (maybe because I was allowing everything before committing the rules above and this connection remained as established / related?)

Comment: I don't know what to say. I loaded the same rules on a test computer, and they work for me. I'll edit my question to show exactly what I have.